# XSS, encoding a return url

Tags: php, html, security, xss

Here is the vulnerable code

```
  <?php header("Location: ".$_POST['target']); ?>
```

What is the appropriate way to make sure nasty things that come in to target are cleaned?

Comment: Uhm, what is the vulnerability here?

Comment: @zerkms: he's using unsanitised user input.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: so what? what can attacker do with that?

Comment: @zerkms: redirect the user to a malicious site.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KXB1Ykf6 Here is the sample code I've written in few minutes. It contains "vulnerable" line (33). I do not validate url. Well, who will hack my sample and redirect me to "yahoo.com"?? Anyone?

Comment: And improved version: http://pastebin.com/Jw4Zp3F5 So, who will hack it, huh? ;-)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First up, this is a vulnerability**

OWASP categorizes it as "Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards". See [OWASP's guide for more information](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10).

A few interesting attacks are possible. See [this thread on sla.ckers.org for ideas](http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,35422) on how this can be abused.

**How do you protect yourself?**

- Verify the scheme of the URL. You usually only want to support http and https. Abort the request for any other scheme.
- Parse the URL, and extract the domain. Only allow redirects to known list of domains. For other domains, abort the request.

That's about it.

Comment: OWASP is meaningful only with GET

Comment: If it is vulnerability, you can try to hack my "vulnerable" code. I added the link in the questions comments.

Comment: @zerkms - Your code has a CSRF token in it, the original question doesn't have that protection. You are not comparing the same thing.

Comment: @sri: so what? He asked is `<?php header("Location: ".$_POST['target']); ?>` vulnerable. I get this complete line unchanged and prove that **it is not**. Don't you agree with it? "the original question doesn't have that protection" -- how do you know that? The only way to attack is to have CSRF vulnerability, which should be solved separately to any header location question.

Comment: It is pointless to say some line is vulnerability just because you have another vulnerability. Let's suppose `echo 123;` is vulnerable. Why would you ask me? Just because ssh root is without password, that is why ;-) the same case.

Comment: @zerkms I agree with sri on this one.  It doesn't matter if its post, you can still fool the referer,  which may undermine CSRF protection or used to fool logs.  For instance an attacker could exploit a GET based XSS vulnerability on another page and obscure the referer of the original attacking site.

Comment: @Rook: can you prove your words? Take my script and do it. Or you can't?

Comment: @zerkms: redirection is merely one thing you could do with HTTP Response Splitting. Other things involve entire manipulation of the response or changing of cookie values. These in turn allow you to even inspect sensitive data such as session identifiers. HTTP Response Splitting can yield in XSS, Session Hijacking, Session Fixation, Account Lockout attacks, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

In old versions of PHP this would be a [CRLF injection vulnerability](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/crlf-injection.htm).   However,  that has been fixed and now its just a [OWASP A10 violation](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10).  So to answer your question,  **YES** it is a vulnerability because it violates OWASP.

Comment: It is a vulnerability because you can inject code. It doesn’t matter whether OWASP said that or not.

Comment: @Gumbo, what exact vulnerability can you create through the HTTP headers of the response to your own request?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Guess what CSRF does. The request must not be deliberately initiated by the user.

Comment: @Gumbo♦: so vulnerability is CSRF, and has nothing to do with Location header.

Comment: If it is vulnerability, you can try to hack my "vulnerable" code. I added the link in the questions comments.

Comment: @zerkms  @Gumbo♦  @Álvaro G. Vicario  This is **not CSRF**, it was a CRLF http response splitting vulnerability which can turn into xss,  but that was fixed years ago.  However this is a clear violation of OWASP even on a fully patched PHP 5 install.

Comment: @Rook: I agree it **was** a CRLF vulnerability, but **now it is not**.

Comment: @zerkms  the exploit for this vulnerability is trivial http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7384/

Comment: @Rook: can you hack **my code** (which contains vulnerable line)?

Comment: crlf would have been a lot nastier than all the redirect stuff. at first I thought some configuration would allow a redirect to "?\n\n<html><script>..." resulting in an affect on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There is no vulnerability.

Even though user can put anything in `$_POST['target']`, so? He will be redirected to the page he wanted. The same as if he just type another url in the address bar, or changed some chars on this page with firebug.

If you worry about CSRF-type attacks, then just make protection against them.

**UPD**:

To the persons who thinks it is a vulnerable and who downvotes me (thank for the downvote for the truth, you just confirmed you have nothing to say, just downvote):

Take this code http://pastebin.com/Jw4Zp3F5 and prove it is a vulnerable.

**UPD 2**:

So, 1 week left. I've got a lot of links to security articles and have read a lot of loud words that **it is** a vulnerability. But **NOONE** has proven that it really is.

So, misters experts, if it is vulnerability, why noone proved that based on my script **with vulnerable line**? Or everything you can only do - is just point to the article and nothing more, huh?

Comment: I'd make it "There is no *XSS* vulnerability", to make more clear

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: there is no vulnerability at all. Header Location is not the source of any vulnerability.

Comment: -1 i guess you have never heard of owasp,  because this is a clear and absolute violation.

Comment: @Rook: so, I gave you a script with "violation". Are you enough competent and experienced to prove it is violation?

Comment: @zerkms: redirection is merely one thing you could do with HTTP Response Splitting. Other things involve entire manipulation of the response or changing of cookie values. These in turn allow you to even inspect sensitive data such as session identifiers. HTTP Response Splitting can yield in XSS, Session Hijacking, Session Fixation, Account Lockout attacks, for instance.

Comment: @Kai Sellgren: could you do any this scary thing you enumerated with my script? Just want to emphasize: my script **does contain** "vulnerable" line. Are you able to use this "vulnerability"? If no - why did you said it is a vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your design and requirement. but I think instead of asking for whole path from user, just ask the differentiating path and add the initials of your own. I mean http://HOSTNAME/$userGivenPath

2nd, if you know the valid paths then validate entry from user against those valid paths.

3rd, if you are using direct $_POST['path'] right now, later you may also use it at other places like require $_POST['']. So, your way of using the POST can be dangerous. So, you should filter the filepath for \.. , \..\.. etc. So, better filter the input and help yourself and other who follow your code write better code.